# Ubuntu 14.04 screen goes black when using youtube with Chrome

Tags: 14.04, google-chrome, youtube

When I am using youtube in my Chrome the entire screen goes black. This has been happening since 4 months ago. The screen goes balck, but still I can hear the music and the OS is still running. 
The only thing that I can do is to force the system to shutdown with the power button.
I have alredy updated the system with the Satware Updater, and still facing the issue. 
The strange part is that when I use Firefox this issue doesnt shows.

I have looked in to similar questions but no good answers still.

Comment: Chrome uses it's own flash player ("pepper" I think), sounds like it's having trouble for some reason. You could try a youtube-only workaround by using HTML5 (youtube's site has a link about activating it somewhere)

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem using Chrome in Ubuntu 14.04 and then again in Fedora 20. What finally worked for me was unchecking the "use hardware acceleration when available" at the bottom of Chrome settings>show advanced settings.

Comment: @JEAM, if this solved your problem then check its acceptance icon.