# Black Screen during browsing

Tags: 14.04, google-chrome, ubuntu-studio

I was browsing with Chrome on Ubuntu Studio 14.04, and the screen suddenly went black. The computer would not respond to anything, so I had to force shutdown and reboot. After, again when I was using Chrome, it gave me the same black screen. How can I fix this?

Comment: Related or duplicate: [This old post](http://askubuntu.com/q/469994/37165) asked on "Google Chrome Black Screen in Xubuntu 14.04" and [another old post](http://askubuntu.com/q/564042/37165) asked on "Ubuntu 14.04 screen goes black when using youtube with Chrome", which have few different answers.

Comment: @clearkimura  No, it is not a duplicate, but it might be related: "Google Chrome Black Screen in Xbuntu 14.04" shows a screenshot of ONLY the chrome window being black. That is not the case, as in my problem, the whole screen turns black. As for "Ubuntu 14.04 screen goes black when using youtube with Chrome", I am not playing any videos.